# Pandas Dataframe: Create a new column and insert a value in a matching row based on two different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (say user_df) with 3 columns {"User_ID", "transaction_id","location"}. I want to create a new column "Amount" and enter a value in a row that matches "User_ID" and "location" columns. How do i do this?

```
  User_id transaction_id  location
0   User1             X1         0
1   User2             X1         0
2   User3             X1         2
3   User4             X2         1
4   User5             X2         2
5   User6             X2         1
6   User7             X3         2
7   User8             X3         2
```

Comment: I have added the sample data. But i dont see why we should use a group by here? i was wondering if we could use iloc or something but twice... once on each column: user_id and location? Basically i want to insert in to this dataframe where user_id = xxxx and location = yyyy

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but I'm still not sure what the "Amount" value should be. What would you want to go in the first row for instance, or is this coming from some other DataFrame?

Comment: Did you try using `loc`? Something like `user_df.loc[(user_df['User_id']== 'User1') & (user_df['location']==0), 'Amount'] = 100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try using `.loc` with `&` for two columns, something like below:

```
user_df.loc[(user_df['User_id']== 'User1') & (user_df['location']==0), 'Amount'] = 100
```

Comment: i tried this and got the following error: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong, did it work fine for the sample?

Comment: thanks. can you take a look at another question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63963304/python-3-making-a-function-call-in-apply-and-handling-multiple-return-values

Answer (score 1):

you'll have `specified_amount` for the columns with `User1` and location '0' and for other cells, you'll have 0

```
df['Amount'] = np.where((user_df['User_id']== 'User1') & (user_df['location']==0), specified_amount, 0)
```

Comment: i tried this and got the following error: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Answer (score 0):

Create a column `'Amount'`

`user_df['Amount'] = 0`

`user_df[(user_df['user_id] == 'xxxx') & (user_df['transaction_id'] == 'yyyy')]['amount'] = 'amount_value'`